# R intercept in arima with xreg

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to understand what the reported intercept is showing when I use `arima()` with `xreg=`. The documentation says

"If am xreg term is included, a linear regression (with a constant term if include.mean is true and there is no differencing) is fitted with an ARMA model for the error term."

Thus I expect the intercept shown to come from the regression using `xreg=` as the X variables, before any arima model is done on those residuals.

However I tried to double check this by actually doing the regression with `lm()` and the intercept from that does not match what is reported from `arima()` (although the slope coefficient is pretty close).

Here is my example:

```
set.seed(456)
v = rnorm(100,1,1)
x = cumsum(v)  ; x = as.xts(ts(x)) 

# Fit AR(1) after taking out a time trend (aka, drift)
model5 = arima(x, order=c(1,0,0), xreg=1:length(x), include.mean=TRUE)
# Coefficients:
#         ar1     intercept  1:length(x)
#       0.8995     0.8815       1.1113
# s.e.  0.0422     1.6193       0.0265


# Double check
MyTime = 1:length(x)
model5_Part1 = lm(x ~ MyTime )
# Coefficients:
#      (Intercept)       MyTime  
#         1.856           1.096
```

The intercepts do not match, thus I do not know what the intercept is showing from the arima with xreg.

Note the example shown is based on "Issue 2" shown here http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/Rissues.htm

Also note that this isn't a problem particular to modeling drift. Here is another example, where in addition to the intercept not matching, even the slope coefficient on the `xreg=` variable doesn't match what is shown from using `lm()`. This example has nothing to do with drift and uses the cars dataset as if it were time series data.

```
data(cars)
cars = as.xts(ts(cars, start=c(1980,1), freq=12))
model6 = arima(cars$speed, xreg=cars$dist, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE)
# Coefficients:
#         ar1    intercept   dist
#       0.9979    15.2890  -0.0172
# s.e.  0.0030    10.5452   0.0055

model6_Part1 = lm(cars$speed ~ cars$dist)
# Coefficients:
#      (Intercept)    cars$dist  
#        8.2839        0.1656
```

Intercepts do not match, slope coefficient does not match.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the differences that you are finding in your modelling is the following.

Suppose you have a left-hand-side variable $y$ and a regressor $x$. Suppose also that the variables are stationary (for simplicity). Then you have the following equations:

**(1a)** $y_t=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x_t+u_t$ 
**(1b)** $u_t=\psi_1u_{t-1}+...+\psi_pu_{t-p}+v_t+\zeta_1v_{t-1}+...+\zeta_qv_{t-q}$

There are two ways you can proceed.

- Case **A**: you estimate equation **(1a)** first, obtain the residuals, then use them to estimate equation **(1b)**.
- Case **B**: you estimate both equations simultaneously.

In case **A**, in the first stage you implicitly make an assumption that the residuals in equation **(1a)** are independent across time. Then in the second stage you revoke this assumption and model the residuals from equation **(1a)** as an ARMA process given by equation **(1b)**. (So there is an intrinsic contradiction between the assumptions in stage 1 and stage 2 that shows the weakness of this approach.)

In case **B**, you assume that the residuals from equation **(1a)** follow an ARMA process as given in equation **(1b)** and use this information when estimating equation **(1a)**.

Thus there is a difference between the two cases; no wonder you get different results in your modelling where I think you are indeed comparing case **A** and case **B**.

I think you incorrectly assume that *"the intercept shown to come from the regression using xreg= as the X variables, before any arima model is done on those residuals".* This is very close to the truth, but not exactly true; you miss the fact that the function `arima()` uses the assumption given by equation **(1b)** when estimating equation **(1a)**.

Thus the difference that you are finding in your modelling is supposed to be there.

There is also a case **C**:

**(2)** $(y_t-\mu_y)=\phi_0+\phi_1(y_{t-1}-\mu_y)+...+\phi_p(y_{t-p}-\mu_y)+\epsilon_t+\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}+...+\theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}+\beta_1x_t$

where $\mu_y$ is the mean of $y$. Not sure, but perhaps one should also subtract the mean of $x$ to make the last term $\beta_1(x_t-\mu_x)$ instead of just $\beta_1x_t$.

Actually, case **C** seems more natural to me than case **B** given how we specify the arguments in `arima()`. Of course, this is subjective judgement. However, the interpretation of the coefficient $\beta_1$ in case **C** is much more difficult than in case **B**.

A nice related piece by prof. Hyndman can be found [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). I borrowed some ideas from there when answering this post, so I can only recommend reading the original piece!

*Disclaimer: I am not an expert on this topic, but I hope I got the idea right. If not, corrections are mostly welcome!*