# How to decide if I should fit SARIMAx with or without intercept

Tags: time-series, arima, intercept

I am trying to find the best SARIMAX model for my data, I am using `auto_arima` to find the order(ARMA and Seasonal) of the model. How do I decide whether or not I should have an intercept in my model?

Also does intercept has an impact on deciding the order of the model.

To give more context, `auto_arima` throws a model with or without intercept depending on what exogenous variable I am using. Which is a little confusing?

Comment: (1) Do you have reason to believe that your series should have zero unconditional mean? (2) Do you think that mean is conditional only on your exogenous variable is subject to variation. Basically in a univariate time series model the mean given past values changes but unconditional mean is fixed. With exogenous variables, I presume, you assume that mean value (unconditional on past values) is conditional on exogenous variable.

Comment: It's sales data, so I think it should be non-zero unconditional mean, although the confusion raised when I was running auto-arima without passing intercept at letting the algorithm of package decide that it was returning a model without intercept for a lot of cases. So I wanted to understand what's the general rule to decide that.

Comment: And I am even more concerned when the intercept is negative.

Comment: If the unconditional mean should be non-zero then you should always specify intercept as otherwise the model selection can get distorted significantly.

Comment: Negative intercept might come with exogenous variable. For example, forget about dependence on past values for a while. Now if you include sales figure of some other item as exogenous variable then you are estimating how the average sales figure of your dependent variable is in terms of sales figure of this other item. If on average always less than a certain fraction of exogenous figure then the intercept can come out negative.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Dayne , It does make sense, although I am not using sales of another item as exogenous rather discount info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127979/discussion-between-mo-dan-and-dayne).

Comment: See this similar posts:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103129/r-intercept-in-arima-with-xreg,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348430/what-is-the-reason-for-not-including-an-intercept-term-in-ar-and-arma-models